# I May Require Some Login Assistance

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

So, I was making a registration form for an HTML-JS based game

But, when I try to make an alert, it just says [`HTMLInputElement`] or something like that. It really ticks me and my colleagues off and this game's progress will fail to a halt, if we don't know the answer.

```js
function log(name){
  alert("Hello, " + name + "!");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src = script.js type = application/javascript>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <! for example:
    Name
    <input type = text id = name>
    <br><br>
    <button id = log onclick = log(name)>Click This</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating 'name' with your alert string, you are actually converting that into a string representation of the object instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a little to make it fit the proper coding conventions, you can see a working copy here http://plnkr.co/edit/EfEaTNcJspzvJnWW8CW0?p=preview

Basically you want to attach an listener to you button and trigger your function when someone clicks on the button.

```
document.getElementById('log').addEventListener('click', logger, false);

function logger() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  alert(name);
}
```